# Using AJAX call success but unable to access variable in PHP but Cookie if accessible

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX and I am having a problem that is driving me crazy.

I have a function that is called based on a user clicking a part of the page. The function is called as so and sends the clicked variables across:

```
"link" => "JavaScript:getTeamMembers($teamID[$teamCount], $lecturer_id)"
```

Here is the function called and my AJAX:

```
function getTeamMembers(teamID,lecturer_id) {

  var teamID = teamID;
  var lecturer_id = lecturer_id;


jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'dashboard.php',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    cache: false,
     data: { teamID: teamID, lecturer_id: lecturer_id },
     success: function(){
        alert("It Works!");
    },
    fail: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    },
    always: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
     }
   ); 
}
```

This is all in the same file **dashboard.php**

Again in dashboard.php, I try and access the data sent as follows:

```
if (!empty($_POST['teamID'])) {

$teamID = $_POST['teamID'];  
$lecturer_id = $_POST['lecturer_id'];


echo $teamID;
echo $lecturer_id;

} else {

echo "no teamID supplied";
}
```

However, I am unable to echo anything. I do get the success callback from my AJAX query. I've tried `var_dump` but nothing.

I ended up giving up on it and used Cookies instead, the following works:

```
function getTeamMembers(teamID,lecturer_id){

// then you store the values in a cookie
document.cookie = "teamID="+teamID; 
document.cookie = "lecturer_id="+lecturer_id;

location.reload();

}
```

I have been successful in accessing the variables here

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["teamID"])) {

$teamID = $_COOKIE["teamID"];   
$lecturer_id = $_COOKIE["lecturer_id"];

echo $teamID;
}
```

The thing is, I don't really want to reload the page to access my data if possible, hence why I am trying to figure out what is happening.

I have `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` included in my file.

Response Header from the console:

```
Request URL:http://foo.co.uk/bar/dashboard.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:xx.xx.xx.xx:xx
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 04 Feb 2018 14:04:26 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=15768000
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:45
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
foo.co.uk
Origin:http://foo.co.uk
Referer:http://foo.co.uk/bar/dashboard.php
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
teamID:73
lecturer_id:59bea8b7d56a63.33388595
```

UPDATE:

I have just discovered that the data I am requesting is available after a page refresh, which is defeating the object of using AJAX.

Comment: Did you checked the response in the development tools ? check the headers & response there.

Comment: @Shan, yep, I have updated my question

Comment: @Dislpay name did you solved the issue ? whats the content of response tab ?

Comment: @Shan no, I didn't unfortunately, I added my response header just above where I wrote the update. Ended up so saving in a cookie and force refresh in the end.